# r.requestBody/r.requestText/r.requestBuffer is undefined (NJS - JavaScript Modules on NGINX)

Tags: javascript, nginx, nginx-config, nginx-module, njs

I'm building a NGINX module with JavaScript, that read incoming requests and design whether to pass them to the proxy server, or to ignore them and return a "block.html" page as a response [kinda WAF].

The problem is when I try to access `r.requestBody/r.requestText/r.requestBuffer` (all three ways should give me the whole request), the variable was `undefined`.

Here are the JavaScript file (that for now has only "reading incoming messages" ability) and NGINX's configuration file:

**waf.js**

```js
function main(r)
{
    return "Request: " + r.requestText;
}

export default { main };
```

**/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf**

```
js_path "/etc/nginx/njs";
js_import waf.js;

js_set $return_value_of_main_func_in_waf waf.main;
log_format ret_val $return_value_of_main_func_in_waf;

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/njs_output.log ret_val;

    location / {
        js_content waf.main;
    }

    location /block.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location @app-backend {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:7777;
    }

    #error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

**njs_output.log**

```
Request: undefined
Request: undefined
Request: undefined
Request: undefined
```

I tried to access other things in the `r` variable, like `r.rawHeadersIn`, and the output was fine:

```
Host,localhost,Connection,keep-alive,Cache-Control,max-age=0,sec-ch-ua,\x22Not?A_Brand\x22;v=\x228\x22, \x22Chromium\x22;v=\x22108\x22, \x22Google Chrome\x22;v=\x22108\x22,sec-ch-ua-mobile,?0,sec-ch-ua-platform,\x22Windows\x22,Upgrade-Insecure-Requests,1,User-Agent,Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36,Accept,text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9,Sec-Fetch-Site,none,Sec-Fetch-Mode,navigate,Sec-Fetch-User,?1,Sec-Fetch-Dest,document,Accept-Encoding,gzip, deflate, br,Accept-Language,he-IL,he;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,Cookie,security_level=0; security=low; PHPSESSID=ruioabebdprspfihjst4vu66he; session=9603a1c6-1fe4-4f93-be1a-68ad6a5738ed.vsLXilN0X5P1XWLCWBveUL1PkW8
```

Answer (score 0):

I found [an issue](https://github.com/nginx/njs/issues/659) on the njs repo for this exact problem. It had a link to [a blog post](https://www.nginx.com/blog/deploying-nginx-plus-as-an-api-gateway-part-2-protecting-backend-services/#request-body-variable) where the solution was to use [the mirror directive](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_mirror_module.html).

e.g.

```
location / {
  # non-existent url but forces body to be read
  mirror /sbVE8Tvdrpjqf0D47mObQ97kzj7JPf
  js_content waf.main;
}
```